# Error creating AnnotationActionEndpointMapping bean

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I have a java 8 spring 5 project / spring ws 3. It is running in tomcat 8. It has been mirgrated from older versions of spring and uses xml configuration of the webservices. When I start the application I am getting the following error

> ERROR: [May-04 15:03:25,263] web.context.ContextLoader - Context
> initialization failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping#0':
> Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> This bean is getting created by Spring and is not specially called by
> my application. I checked the code here
>
> [Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/xref/org/springframework/ws/soap/addressing/server/AnnotationActionEndpointMapping.html)
>
> and looked at all the constructors getting called but still can't
> figure out what could be going wrong. Anyone ever see this? Or have
> any idea what I could look at to track down the error?
>
> Thanks
>
> Edit: Should have added the final exception
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
> org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionFactory.createXPathExpression(XPathExpressionFactory.java:73)
> at
> org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.version.AbstractAddressingVersion.createNormalizedExpression(AbstractAddressingVersion.java:116)
> at
> org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.version.AbstractAddressingVersion.(AbstractAddressingVersion.java:88)
> at
> org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.version.Addressing200408.(Addressing200408.java:36)
> at
> org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.initDefaultStrategies(AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.java:107)
> at
> org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.(AbstractAddressingEndpointMapping.java:98)
> at
> org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractActionEndpointMapping.(AbstractActionEndpointMapping.java:38)
> at
> org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AbstractActionMethodEndpointMapping.(AbstractActionMethodEndpointMapping.java:34)
> at
> org.springframework.ws.soap.addressing.server.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping.(AnnotationActionEndpointMapping.java:60)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)

**Edit 2:**
The last line of code that runs is
org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionFactory.java:36

This calls
`org.springframework.xml.xpath.Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory.createXPathExpression()` with the following data

```
expression = normalize-space(wsa:To)
namespaces = ["wsa" -> "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"]
```

I have a break point in `Jaxp13XPathExpressionFactory.createXPathExpression()` but it never gets hit. Puzzled why this is, it says it can't find the class but the class is in the same package as the class calling it.

**Edit 3.**
It actually does find the class, breakpoints in intellij weren't working so well. The error seems to be caused by

```
jar:file:.../saxon9he-9.2.1.5.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:2: Illegal configuration-file syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer in the end. Was an old maven dependency causing the issue. I upgraded saxon9he v9.2.1.5 to Saxon-HE v9.8.0-11 and the error no longer occurs and my app starts without issue.